# primefaces 4: Multiple autocomplete add an element in middle of eneterd items

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I am using a multiple autocomplete. I add some 4-5 items in multi autocomplete box. Is it possible to add an item in the middle (say between 2nd & 3rd item)

As we see in gmail, in the To field when we specify multiple emails, its possible to drag an email id item to any where in the list.

I tried in PF Showcase for multi-autocomplete where its not possible to drag or add an item between, instead we need to remove all items to the position where we need to add the new one.

Please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: Its a bussiness requirement in project

Comment: 'Answers' like this always trigger questions... like: "what fails if the tags are not in an order or are not draggable to be put in order?" In the gmail example: nothing... You can always combine a single autocomplete with e.g. an  OrderList. I inspected the generated html source (of 5.2), and manipulating that is difficult, so there is no other option I think to either change the real source of the component or request a paid improvement or go with another component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible th PrimeFaces 4 (nor with newer releases afaik)

I took a look at the generated html to see if there was an easy workaround, but there is not. It can be done, but requires a fair amount of javascript overriding... capturing left/right movement, mouse clicks, putting the selection at the right place in the 'hidden' options list etc... To much work (at least for me) to do for you...