# Autocomplete: Edit items

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to edit items before the last one in a Primefaces autocomplete field:

```
<p:autoComplete multiple="true" ... />
```

It's possible to delete the item before with the mouse, but not to change it or go back with cursor left. If I edit the "Tags" field of Stackoverflow questions, it's for example possible to click on an item, which is transformed to editable text and an autocompletion is visible for inner tags too. Any idea of how to achieve this with p:autocomplete? Even the http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete seems not sufficient, as it has no autocompletion for inner items. I still need PF 'itemSelect' and 'itemUnselect' events. There is a similar question at [primefaces 4: Multiple autocomplete add an element in middle of eneterd items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784601) where the conclusion is, that it's currently not possible (but with hard JS extensions). I might have to open a PF enhancement request or are there other JS solutions? A solution could be to create many dynamic autocompletes with multiple="false".

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2481

Answer (score 0):

You could use PrimeFaces [autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) component with multiple input.

Try it typing for example Home, Bootstrap, Casablanca...

Comment: I already use multiple elements but want to edit the first one